# Match word starting with and ending

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I'm trying to write a grep expression that matches any word starting with "h" and ending with "d". So it should return words like "head" "heard" "hammered"

Tried this expression but it returned nothing.

```
grep -o '^h\w*d\b' file.txt
```

Comment: Do you mean `\bh\w*d\b` ? or `\bh\w+d\b`, not sure bd is a word. Try `grep -Eo '\bh\w+d\b' file.txt`

Comment: True. The "*" searches for zero or more characters so I didn't believe it would make a huge difference.

Comment: Then I think it could be `grep -o '\bh\w*d\b' file.txt`

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Can you explain a little what I had mixed up in my expression?

Comment: The answer with an explanation is already posted. You could use a word boundary `\b` instead of asserting the start of the string `^` Your pattern would match those words if they are at the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression is mostly correct, however `^` matches the beginning of input -- that's likely not what you want.  You probably want to substitute a `\b` for the `^` to match a word boundary at the beginning.

The following expression should work.

```
grep -o '\bh\w*d\b' file.txt
```